# How do I uninstall gfortran and have the new installed version into the same file as my Xcode for Mac computer?

Tags: xcode, macos, gfortran

I would like to uninstall gfortran on my computer and install gfortran on my Mac computer. It looks like gfortran is not in the same folder where it should be (it should be in the same folder as my xcode). See the code below. What commands should I put in the terminal on my mac to uninstall gfortran and upload gfortran into the correct folder?
I plan to download gfortran 13.2 for Sonoma (Macbook Pro Apple M2, Sonoma 14.0) and want to check that this is installed correctly. I'm a bit new to this so any help is appreciated!

I wanted to include an example of the code that came out when I used terminal on my mac

```
Last login: Tue Mar 19 14:44:57 on ttys000
(base) cherry@cherries-MacBook-Pro ~ % which xcode-select
/usr/bin/xcode-select
(base) cherry@cherries-MacBook-Pro ~ % which gfortran
/opt/homebrew/bin/gfortran
(base) cherry@cherries-MacBook-Pro ~ %
```

Comment: Welcome, I sugggest taking the [tour] and reading [ask]. Why would you expect gfortran to be in the same directory as Xcode? There is no reason for that. According to the output you show, Gfortran came from Homebrew, but Xcode came directly from Apple.